# Are there any major pitfalls using PostgreSQL as a replacement for SqlSever

Tags: .net, sql-server, postgresql

I'm just looking at the possibility of using postgresql as an alternative to sqlserver for a .NET web app.

(as a cloud hosted sqlserver costs an arm and a leg once the size of your data is over 20GB or so)

so really looking for something with reasonably good performance that can hold a lot of data.

However, I'm not entirely sure what I'm going to be losing by going to posgresql that might *seriously* start to hurt.

I'm not too worried by minor issues, or any issues in terms of porting ( unless there's major blocking issues of porting).

We use NHibernate, Linq, as well as raw sql against the database  ( its a legacy product thats slowly being migrated to NHibernate as its data access tech)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are using features of SQL Server that are not available in PostgreSQL you should be fine. I'm using both PostgreSQL and SQL Server on a daily basis and both work just fine for a .NET based application accessing the database through ADO.NET and/or NHibernate. NHibernate has proven to be a good approach to isolate my code from the differences between these (and other) database servers.

Comment: I do find that a downside is that after spending some time coding with Postgres, I feel a little sad coding with another DB though :)